# Downloading a protected/view-only text (.txt) file from Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-drive-api, text-files, developer-tools

I have not managed to figure out how to download a protected/view-only text file from Google Drive using Chrome Developer Tools (i.e., the console) or another tool. I would be most grateful if you help me solve this.

Comment: I cannot understand `protected/view-only text file`. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike Sure, don't worry. I am trying to download a .txt file from Google Drive without permission, i.e., the file's owner has disabled the download option for that file.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand `protected/view-only text file`. In that case, unfortunately, I think that the file cannot be downloaded. I apologize for this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.